# Server Error in '/' application while trying to sign in as an FBA user?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication

I have setup windows and forms based authentication on one of my web applications and have an issue while trying to sign in as fbaadmin. fbaadmin is one of the users I have added to the FBADB on SQL2008 through .NET users from IIS. 
I have no issue signing in using windows authentication but am unable to use the FBA user. 
I am also unable to even bring up the sign in page outside of the server.
I get the same error screen in both cases.
Here is a screenshot for reference.
Please advise.
Thanks
[image: FBA Sign in error]

[image: Event Log]

Comment: How about posting some relevant log information?

Comment: @rjcup3 I have attached a screenshot of the error from event logs Could you please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made the required changes to the web.config files in each of the following locations?

1. SharePoint Central Administration
2. Security Token Service ([SharePoint root]\WebServices\SecurityToken)
3. Your web application

Should you wish to modify the web.config files by hand (do so carefully!), the instructions can be found in step III of [this walk-through](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mahesm/archive/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx).

Alternately, you can make these same changes through the IIS admin interface. Detailed procedures for doing that can be found [here](http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/).

I recall receiving similar errors to the ones you are seeing when I first set up FBA in SharePoint 2010 and did not correctly modify the STS web.config. Failing that, you can also set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"` in the `<serviceDebug>` element of your STS web.config to get additional error information, as suggested in the screenshot from Event Viewer you posted above.